# Ruby split string and preserve separator

Tags: ruby, string, symbols

In Ruby, what's the easiest way to split a string in the following manner?

- `'abc+def'` should split to `['abc', '+', 'def']`
- `'abc\*def+eee'` should split to `['abc', '\*', 'def', '+', 'eee']`
- `'ab/cd*de+df'` should split to `['ab', '/', 'cd', '*', 'de', '+', 'df']`

The idea is to split the string about these symbols: `['-', '+', '*', '/']` and also save those symbols in the result at appropriate locations.

Comment: hint: `.split` accepts regular expressions

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages. We need to see evidence of your effort toward solving the problem. Did you write code? If no, why not? Where did you search to find a solution? If you didn't search, why? Currently your question looks like a plea for us to write the code for you, which isn't what SO is for.

Comment: @theTinMan Sorry, about that. I will keep that in mind in asking questions in the future.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Option 1**

`/\b/` is a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) and it has zero-width, so it will not consume any characters

```
'abc+def'.split(/\b/)
# => ["abc", "+", "def"]

'abc*def+eee'.split(/\b/)
# => ["abc", "*", "def", "+", "eee"]

'ab/cd*de+df'.split(/\b/)
# => ["ab", "/", "cd", "*", "de", "+", "df"]
```

---

**Option 2**

If your string contains other word boundary characters and you only want to split on `-`, `+`, `*`, and `/`, then you can use [capture groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html). If a capture group is used, `String#split` will also include captured strings in the result. (Thanks for pointing this out [@Jordan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179125/jordan)) ([@Cary Swoveland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256970/cary-swoveland) sorry, I didn't see your answer when I made this edit)

```
'abc+def'.split /([+*\/-])/
# => ["abc", "+", "def"]

'abc*def+eee'.split /([+*\/-])/
# => ["abc", "*", "def", "+", "eee"]

'ab/cd*de+df'.split /([+*\/-])/
# => ["ab", "/", "cd", "*", "de", "+", "df"]
```

---

**Option 3**

Lastly, for those using a language that might not support string splitting with a capture group, you can use two [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Lookarounds are also zero-width matches, so they will not consume any characters

```
'abc+def'.split /(?=[+*\/-])|(?<=[+*\/-])/
# => ["abc", "+", "def"]

'abc*def+eee'.split /(?=[+*\/-])|(?<=[+*\/-])/
# => ["abc", "*", "def", "+", "eee"]

'ab/cd*de+df'.split /(?=[+*\/-])|(?<=[+*\/-])/
# => ["ab", "/", "cd", "*", "de", "+", "df"]
```

The idea here is to split on any character that is preceded by one of your separators, or any character that is followed by one of the separators. Let's do a little visual

```
ab ⍿ / ⍿ cd ⍿ * ⍿ de ⍿ + ⍿ df
```

The little `⍿` symbols are either preceded or followed by one of the separators. So this is where the string will get cut.

---

**Option 4**

Maybe your language doesn't have a string `split` function or sensible ways to interact with regular expressions. It's nice to know you don't have to sit around guessing if there's clever built-in procedures that magically solve your problems. There's almost always a way to solve your problem using basic instructions

```
class String
  def head
    self[0]
  end
  def tail
    self[1..-1]
  end
  def reduce acc, &f
    if empty?
      acc
    else
      tail.reduce yield(acc, head), &f
    end
  end
  def separate chars
    res, acc = reduce [[], ''] do |(res, acc), char|
      if chars.include? char
        [res + [acc, char], '']
      else
        [res, acc + char]
      end
    end
    res + [acc]    
  end
end

'abc+def'.separate %w(- + / *)
# => ["abc", "+", "def"]

'abc*def+eee'.separate %w(- + / *)
# => ["abc", "*", "def", "+", "eee"]

'ab/cd*de+df'.separate %w(- + / *)
# => ["ab", "/", "cd", "*", "de", "+", "df"]
```

Comment: Great! Especially the lookarounds. Thanks a lot. Cheers!

Comment: Nice explanation too.

Comment: The lookaround is overkill. `String#split` will preserve captures, so all you need is `string.split /([+*\/-])/`.

Comment: The second example string is `'abc\*def+eee'`, not `'abc*def+eee'`, but good answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland the original question was not written that way :(

Comment: I was late to the party so didn't see that. Teeth still good?

Comment: @CarySwoveland lol, I haven't used that avatar in quite a while.

Answer (score 3):

I see this is close to part of @naomic's answer, but I'll leave it for the small differences.

```
splitters = ['-', '+', '*', '/']

r = /(#{ Regexp.union(splitters) })/ 
  # => /((?-mix:\-|\+|\*|\/))/

'abc+def'.split r
  #=> ["abc", "+", "def"] 
"abc\*def+eee".split r
  #=> ["abc", "*", "def", "+", "eee"] 
'ab/cd*de+df'.split r
  #=> ["ab", "/", "cd", "*", "de", "+", "df"]
```

Notes:

- the regex places `#{ Regexp.union(splitters) }` in a capture group, causing [String#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-split) to include the strings that do the splitting (last sentence of the third paragraph).
- the second example string must be in double quotes in order to escape `*`.

Comment: Nice use of `Regexp.union`. Glad I learned that `String#split` allows use of capture groups. I never knew that before ^_^